# error hetting while iteration over list and dictionary

Tags: python, indentation

```
import os
import sys

lst = ["ABCD", "LMN" , "STU" , "PQRS" ]

dict = { 'ABCD':'kajal' , 'LMN' :'John' , 'PQRS' : 'Anni'}

for i in lst:
    for k,l in dict.items():
        if i == k:
            print(i,l)
        else:
            print(i,"no id")
```

output :

```
('ABCD', 'kajal')
('ABCD', 'no id')
('ABCD', 'no id')
('LMN', 'no id')
('LMN', 'no id')
('LMN', 'John')
('STU', 'no id')
('STU', 'no id')
('STU', 'no id')
('PQRS', 'no id')
('PQRS', 'Anni')
('PQRS', 'no id')
```

Expected output :

```
('ABCD', 'kajal')
('LMN', 'John')
('STU', 'no id')
('PQRS', 'Anni')
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason yours is not working is because you are checking each item three times, where you only need to check it one time.

For each item in your list, you are checking it against every key/value pair in the dictionary; since there are three keys, you get three outputs for each item in your list.

Try something simple:

```
for i in lst:
   print(tuple(i, dict.get(i, 'no id')))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, avoid using variable names like `dict` - it masks the standard function with the same name.  You are iterating once through the list, and then for the dictionary.  Here is an alternative method:

```
lst = ["ABCD", "LMN" , "STU" , "PQRS" ]

mydict = { 'ABCD':'kajal' , 'LMN' :'John' , 'PQRS' : 'Anni'}

for i in lst:
    if i in mydict:
        print(i,mydict[i])
    else:
        print(i,"no id")
```

Using the `in` keyword tests for the presence of a key.

By the way, the presence of the `( )` in the output suggests you are using python 3 syntax for your `print` statement in python 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import sys

lst = ["ABCD", "LMN" , "STU" , "PQRS" ]

dict = { 'ABCD':'kajal' , 'LMN' :'John' , 'PQRS' : 'Anni'}

for i in lst:
    if i in dict:
        print(i, dict[i])
    else:
        print(i, "no id")
```

Simply, you iterated over the dict too, hence the multiple entiries

Answer (score 0):

```
def list_from_dict(id, dictionary):
    if id in dictionary.keys():
        return id, dictionary[id]
    else:
        return id,"no id"

lst = ["ABCD", "LMN" , "STU" , "PQRS" ]
dic = { 'ABCD':'kajal' , 'LMN' :'John' , 'PQRS' : 'Anni'}

for items in lst:
    print(list_from_dict(items,dic))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for solution:)

Comment: @Kajal you can upvote and accept as answer if solution works for your problem.